# Getting started with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have come across an issue when trying to modify a file. namely the Index.cshtml file on the Microsoft.com page. the link that I am looking at is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view#comments-container

I am trying to open it to place code into it as per the instructions. however it keeps showing this 
 [dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/020R5.png)

I cant understand why this is happening as I have followed the instructions, only doing as it says. How to sort this issue out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page could probably being rendered through the Viewbag.
Look for the Controller and verify if the Viewbag has the text you're looking for.

Comment: thanks i was in the worng controler file.. I appriciate the help